# Error on Server Response Illegal Character

Tags: jquery, error-handling, server, response

I have a problem on my server that I can't understand.

Randomly when loading static js file and seeing the load with firebug, I can see this error message:

SyntaxError: illegal character

���l�FÀ\�I�O�k�5����Ku8߷���fe����q���Z��%är���  A'

I say that its randomly because the js file with this problem is different every time I reload and sometimes not js trigger this error when reload, all is ok. So I am cofused, I don't know where is the problem and how to fix it.

When this error occurs and depending on wich js file appears, this make entire web not working (example: if js not loaded correctly is jquery then jquery not works on the page so nothing works on it)

You can see a firebug capture of error on: http://mytestserver.com.es/captura-firebug.png

Remember every load the error can be on differente js or not be.

Anyone have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your files might have a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If that's the case, get rid of it and use UTF-8.

Comment: I have tested the last file that gave me this error and with Notepad++ is marked "UTF8 without BOM". Also this not explain why the file with error is randomly and sometimes there is no error.